# In Laravel 5.7, How to override Tymon Jwt-Auth Middleware in Kernel?

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-middleware, jwt

I'm using Laravel 5.7 for some api. I'm also using package https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth to generate JWT tokens to authenticate users. I have configured everything long time ago and it works well.

I register Route group in `RouteServiceProvider.php` under `routes/api_v1.php` :

```
Route::prefix('api/v1')
     ->middleware('api')
     ->namespace($this->namespace.'\API\V1')
     ->group(base_path('routes/api_v1.php'));
```

In `config.auth.php` I have api_v1 guard with driver jwt :

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api_v1' => [
        'driver' => 'jwt',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
],
```

I have made `App/User.php` implemented `Tymon\JWTAuth\Contracts\JWTSubject` and implemented the 2 methods.

But when in `app/Http/Kernel.php` I added in middlewares array :

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    // previous middlewares,
    'jwt.auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\JWTAuthenticate::class
];
```

The Routes in `routes/api_v1.php` under the group `jwt.auth`:

Route::middleware(['jwt.auth'])->group(function() {

```
// Keep auto resource route at bottom to prevent route conflict with Show parameter route
foreach(Controller::$resourceModels as $key => $model) {
    //Route::post($key.'/{id}/patch', $model.'Controller@patchUpdate');
    Route::resource($key, $model.'Controller');
}
```

});

never reach middleware `App\Http\Middleware\JWTAuthenticate::class` but always go to the original tymon package middleware `Tymon\JWTAuth\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class`.

Even if I don't put api driver to jwt in `auth.php` config, and I don't put any `jwt.auth` class in Middleware it's working normally with original middleware.

What I need is for the Routes group to go to my own middleware class `App/Http/Middlewares/JWTAuthenticate` :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Tymon\JWTAuth\Http\Middleware\Authenticate;

use Closure;

class JWTAuthenticate extends Authenticate
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     *
     * @throws \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\UnauthorizedHttpException
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        // My own logics here
        // ...


        $this->authenticate($request);

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

and this way I can override `handle` method and check for my own things first.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can tell you why it happens.

The file `app\Http\Kernel.php` with the middleware config, gets called earlier than registering the service providers.

The Tymon JWT service provider gets therefore called afterwards and sets middleware aliases for:

- 'jwt.auth' =>  Tymon\JWTAuth\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
- 'jwt.check' => Tymon\JWTAuth\Http\Middleware\Check::class,
- 'jwt.refresh' => Tymon\JWTAuth\Http\Middleware\RefreshToken::class,
- 'jwt.renew' => Tymon\JWTAuth\Http\Middleware\AuthenticateAndRenew::class,

thus overriding your key.

So using another middleware key is therefore the right way to use your own implementation.

Comment: I already made it work, but since I didn't understand why I think your answer is more relevant for others. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I renamed the middleware route group and changed

```
Route::middleware(['jwt.auth'])->group(function() {
```

to

```
Route::middleware(['jwt.authenticate'])->group(function() {
```

and

```
'jwt.auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\JWTAuthenticate::class
```

to

```
'jwt.authenticate' => \App\Http\Middleware\JWTAuthenticate::class
```

And the original `jwt.auth` was not called anymore. I don't know why but I can control it now in my Middleware.